# DynamicResource not working

Tags: wpf, dynamicresource

I have a CustomControl library with a control defined as follows :

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Test"
                 Color="Red" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource Test}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which works fine.

However, if I change 'StaticResource' to 'DynamicResource', the red is no longer picked up?

Why is this?

Comment: It's strange. It works for me.

Comment: I should point out that the code above was in a library and not the application exe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to merge resource dictionary. Add reference to ResourceDictionary that contains style for your CustomControl1 to App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/AssemblyName;component/PathToResourceDictionary"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

A StaticResource will be resolved and assigned to the property during the loading of the XAML which occurs before the application is actually run. It will only be assigned once and any changes to resource dictionary ignored.

A DynamicResource assigns an Expression object to the property during loading but does not actually lookup the resource until runtime when the Expression object is asked for the value. This defers looking up the resource until it is needed at runtime. A good example would be a forward reference to a resource defined later on in the XAML. Another example is a resource that will not even exist until runtime. It will update the target if the source resource dictionary is changed.

Hope this will help.

Comment: How come it works without doing the stuff you mentioned with StaticResource? I've never seen custom control libraries merged in this way (I thought adding a reference to the dll was enough to pick up the Themes\Generic.xaml)

Comment: If you use StaticResource then the Background value is assigned before loading from custom control library. If you use DynamicResource then the Background value will be assigned during loading and the application will be looking for DynamicResource in Application resources. Therefore you need to merge resource dictionary.

Comment: But in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#staticdynamic (see dynamic resource lookup) it says that if the dynamic resource is not found in the application resources, the theme is searched.